# Possible to upload from a subdomain to the main domain?

Tags: php

Ok so this is my server structure...

```
ROOT
  -PUBLIC_HTML
     --IMAGES
  -SUBDOMAIN
```

As you can see, the subdomain is located on the root alongside the public_html.
How can i upload a file from the subdomain (subdomain.site.com) to the public_html/images (site.com/images) folder? or is this not possible?

Thanks.

Comment: since php is a server side language and can access almost any of the files under the root it should work.

Comment: If i'm in the subdomain (subdomain.site.com) i dont know how to access the folders inside public_html. Also why the downvote?

Comment: was not me but I can balance it out :).  You would reference `__DIR__ . '/public_html/images';` in the php code.  Are you asking about an html reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upload your file just have your `move_uploaded_file()` move the file to the desired location in the main domain's directory.

If you're using `open_basedir` make sure you have rights to write to your main domain's directories.

> Added the **example** code below - you will have to tweak it to make it work for you

The easiest way is to use an absolute path. You could use something like this

```
// let's assume your upload code is here: /var/www/subdomain.mysite.com/my-upload-code.php

// your desired location
$myImageDir = '/var/www/mysite.com/my-images/' ;

$fileName = basename($_FILES['pictures']['name']) ;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pictures']['tmp_name'], $myImageDir . $fileName) ;
```

Comment: You say move to the desired location, but how do i reach that location when its one level above? its a level up from subdomain.site.com

Comment: @FoxyFish The parent directory can be accecssed with `..`. For example to access a sister directory, just do: `__DIR__ . '/../other_directory`.

Comment: Thank you for that example. Ive never worked with absolute paths before so was unsure how to use it. So the server will know that /var/www/mysite.com/images/ is a root path and not just a subfolder structure like www.mysite.com/var/www/.....etc

Comment: Right. Starting the path with `/` tells the server to start at the root of the file system.

Comment: Ok i see now. Thank you for your help i appreciate it, your answer was very informative :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case my sub domain and main domain were both inside the public_html.

public_html:

- `sub domain`
- `uploads`

uploading happens in sub domain. So in my file path variable I just added `../`

```
 ex: $path = "../uploads"
```

to go outside the current directory from subdomain to maindomain.